ORA-22905: cannot access rows from a non-nested table item. replace multiple characters
Below Code is throwing error. PLease help.
ORA-22905: cannot access rows from a non-nested table item
22905. 00000 -  "cannot access rows from a non-nested table item"
*Cause:    attempt to access rows of an item whose type is not known at
parse time or that is not of a nested table type
*Action:   use CAST to cast the it
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE custom.TBL_VARCHAR2 IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(250);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION custom.FN_REPLACETEXT(
    pText IN VARCHAR2, 
    pPar IN custom.TBL_VARCHAR2
) RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
    vText VARCHAR2(32767);
    vPos INT;
    vValue VARCHAR2(250);

    CURSOR cuParameter(POS INT) IS
    SELECT VAL
        FROM
            (
            SELECT VAL, ROWNUM AS RN 
            FROM (
                  SELECT COLUMN_VALUE VAL
                  FROM TABLE(pPar)
                  )
            )
        WHERE RN=POS+1;
BEGIN
    vText := pText;
    FOR i IN 1..REGEXP_COUNT(pText, '[{][0-9]+[}]') LOOP
        vPos := TO_NUMBER(SUBSTR(REGEXP_SUBSTR(pText, '[{][0-9]+[}]',1,i),2, LENGTH(REGEXP_SUBSTR(pText, '[{][0-9]+[}]',1,i)) - 2));

        OPEN cuParameter(vPos);
        FETCH cuParameter INTO vValue;
        IF cuParameter%FOUND THEN
            vText := REPLACE(vText, REGEXP_SUBSTR(pText, '[{][0-9]+[}]',1,i), vValue);
        END IF;
        CLOSE cuParameter;
    END LOOP;

    RETURN vText;

EXCEPTION
      WHEN OTHERS
      THEN
         RETURN pText;
END FN_REPLACETEXT;
/

select * from custom.FN_REPLACETEXT('Hello {0}, this is a {2} for {1}', custom.TBL_VARCHAR2('world','all','message'));

For ex: Hello {0}, this is a {1} for {2}
I want to replace {0} with FRINEDS and {1} with SAMPLE and {2} with DYNAMIC_STRING

Functions that return scalar data types should be called in the SELECT clause, not the FROM clause. For example:
select FN_REPLACETEXT('Hello {0}, this is a {2} for {1}', TBL_VARCHAR2('world','all','message'))
from dual;

